# C# - Adding an image file from resources in constructor

Tags: c#, image, properties, constructor, resources

I made a custom button class in Visual Studio, and I would like to add an image to the constructor. The images are in the Properties/Resources of my project. Normally, I would add an image to my button like this:

```
btnBack.Image = Properties.Resources.back57;
```

In this scenario, back57 is the name of the image file.

This is the current constructor of my button class:

```
public MenuButton()
    {
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("TrsNo__", 18);
        this.Width = 160;
        this.Height = 40;
        this.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;
        this.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
        this.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(mouseEnterCustom);
        this.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(mouseLeaveCustom);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
    }
```

How to edit the constructor so I can add image files from resources?

Edit 1: I assume it will look something like this.

```
public MenuButton(??????)
    {
    this.Image = ?????????
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add new cunstructor:

```
public MenuButton(Bitmap buttonImage)
   : base()
{
   this.Image = buttonImage
}
```

and create your button:

```
MenuButton menuBttn = new MenuButton(Properties.Resources.back57);
```